# How can I use Owl Carousel 2 in Angular2?

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

I've been trying to get Owl Carousel 2 to work in my Angular2 project without much luck.

Can someone post a step-by-step guide on how to successfully set it up?

Comment: It will be the same as using any external library, just import it and you will be able to use it directly within any of [Angular life cycle hooks](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html)

Comment: Thanks Murhaf. I've tried doing that but get the error 'TypeError: this.carousel.nativeElement.owlCarousel is not a function'.

I call the method from ngOnInit using:
this.$owlElement = this.carousel.nativeElement.owlCarousel(this.defaultOptions);

I've think everything is setup - including installing JQuery, adding Owl Carousel assets and referencing the scripts in .angular-cli.json but still not working.
Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

install jQuery `npm install --save jquery` (because it is a dependency)

install it `npm install --save owl.carousel`

Import the library in **polyfills.ts**

```
import "jquery"
import "owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min"
```

*Make sure that the path to library is correct and don't forget to import the stylesheet* in the global style **style.css** (not the component style)

```
@import "~owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min"
```

Now in your component (Updated)

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
      <div> Your Content </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  
  ngOnInit() {
      jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
  }
}
```

*Ofcourse you can do it better but I wrote this as quick as possible.*

I would go with [Flickity carousel](https://flickity.metafizzy.co) because it is touch, responsive and has no dependency for jQuery

Comment: Exellent thank you, that works great :)


One slight change that I made on your answer was importing the following in style.css:

    @ import "~owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css";
    @ import "~owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css";

One thing I noticed is that I see a 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined' in the developer console in the browser.

The carousel seems to work fine though but I want to try to fix the error anyway, and idea on fixing that?

Comment: @Hallupa I updated the answer, Try to change `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: Thanks Murhaf - that didn't fix the 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined' message but I found if I add a reference to the JQuery script in the head section of index.html that fixed it

Comment: That error probably means that the carousel script was loaded before jQuery script

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there any other way to force JQuery to load before Owl Carousel? I think including it in the head section of index.html means I'm now loading it twice